# EFCore - Get specific property from an List of collections in a DbSet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class country

```
public string id;
public string Name;
public List<Language> Languages;
```

and another class Language:

```
public string Id;
public string Name;
```

how do I write an EFCore query to find the list of countries that speak a specific language?

Comment: `dbContext.Countries.Where(country => country.Languages.Contains(yourLanguage))`